# How can I activate a piston only for a few seconds when the the daylight sensor activates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am trying to make a circuit that turns a piston on for a few seconds and then quickly turns it off.
The circuit is activated as soon as the daylight sensor starts giving signal.

Answer (score 4):

This circuit does exactly what you want:

[image]

Remember to use the comparator to switch its mode.

**Video Demonstration**

Comment: Innovative solution! I thought of something that uses a monostable + pulse extender, but this only requires one comparator. Nice!